# Iptables in a game server

Tags: linux, vpn, firewall, iptables, centos-7

So i admin a game server of a fairly old game with a fairly large cheater problem. I've been using iptables/ipset to help combat some of the more persistant cheaters.

My question is: Is it possible to make it that when i drop a connection to the server they are still able to see it on the server list but unable to join it. With my current config once i decide to drop a connection it vanishes off the server list for them. Which they are using to their advantage somewhat by cylcing their ip/vpn untill they can see the server again and then join.

I have tried using REJECT instead of DROP but the server still vanishes off the game list for the affected connections. Is this something to do with the way i have the iptables configured or is "this just how things work". I'm fairly inexperienced with ipset and iptables and i am mostly self taught taking nuggets of advice where i can get them.

Also as a 2nd question is their an easier way to blanket block VPN connections to the server, my process at the moment is identifying the VPN, getting the ips linked under the ASN and getting them to ipset under a rule to drop.

Comment: What game/protocol?

Comment: @davidgo here is a gif of my iptables just fullscreen it to make it somewhat readable https://gyazo.com/244b721e22dd36e746c0eb9ff2675c5d its an older game in the battlefield series number 2 to be exact

Answer (score 0):

O expect the answer to both questions is no, although there might be some things specific in the protocol used (which has bit been specified) which could change that answer.

One thing you might be able to do is heavily throttle bandwidth so that once they connect the game is unplayable for them.

You cant simply block access coming from all VPNs - there is no single authorative list of VPNs.  It is likely counter-prosuxtive, but you could take the opposite approach of requiring people to authenticate before they can connect. (ie default deny rather then default allow)